How do I specify a user secret in a .NET Core console app?
I've created a .NET 8 Console app. I have also created a user secret with a connection string to one of our SQL Server databases, that looks like this:

{   "TTConnectionString": {
"ConnectionString": "Server=OURSERVER;Database=OURDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=True;"   } }

Then I tried to scaffold the database into a Models folder following what I found here. In the Package Manager Console I've issued commands like this: Scaffold-DbContext 'Name=TTConnectionString:ConnectionString' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer but no matter what how I specify the command in Package Manager Console, in VS 2022, I keep getting errors like this:

A named connection string was used, but the name 'TTConnectionString:ConnectionString' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application.

What am I doing wrong?

Does EF expect the connection string config key to be in a particular location within the config dictionary, such as directly within the ConnectionStrings top-level object, or at the root? How do you setup your IConfiguration and service provider?

I don't know the answer to your first question. I've read about the IConfiguration, but not seen an example of how to set it up.

Maybe you have to treat your console app as a WinForms or WPF app (using App.Config). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

OK, I could do that. This app is meant to be used by me in a one-and-done fashion, I don't care what sort of app it is, so long as I can do several iterative processes to a table in a database. I'll do it as a WinForms or WPF app.
